# How to implement a hidden service with bridges?

Tags: onion-services, torsocks

If my ISP blocks access to tor nodes, I would get bridge info from official tor website and connect tor again but how can I make my hidden service to use bridges ? Does hidden service even need bridges or just the end user needs bridges ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the user need bridges to host a hidden service if the ISP blocks Tor.

Add the bridges and the hidden service lines to your torrc file and run Tor normally.